# Meaning of the Japanese "Kanteishi" in English

Tags: translation

This is linked to my other question there: [https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62852/meaning-of-鑑定士-in-english-or-french](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62852/meaning-of-%E9%91%91%E5%AE%9A%E5%A3%AB-in-english-or-french)

I'm trying to translate the word Japanese word "Kanteishi" in English.

The person I have in mind is the one that this an expert about a type of goods (e.g. brand bags, diamonds, luxury watches), and is able to recognize and value them. He often use his knowledge in pawn shops or in auctions of such goods.

The term "appraiser" seems close enough, but I have the feeling it has a different nuance.

** EDIT **

I was afraid that appraiser is a kind of obsolete words, but it looks it isn't.

Does it designate a person that owns a very specific diploma, such as lawyers, or is it a broader term? I'm looking for a broad term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appraiser is exactly the word you're looking for.

From [Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appraiser):

> An appraiser (from Latin appretiare, "to value"), is one who determines the fair market value of property, real or personal. In England the business of an appraiser is usually combined with that of an auctioneer, while the word itself has a similar meaning to that of "valuer."

Answer (score 1):

A broad term could be simply "expert"

> The auction house asked for an expert in Chinese porcelain to inspect the Ming vase to determine if it was genuine and estimate its value.

Particular fields may have specific names. For example, a professional who inspects buildings is a "chartered surveyor" (but this is a particular diploma)